# grouping in dplyr with missing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a complex `dplyr` structure within a function call. The input is a data frame which can have an extra column called `s`. If this column is available, I want to group by this column additionally to the standard grouping. 
At the moment I solved it by an `if` statement checking if the column is in the data frame and make the grouping differently. After the grouping I have the same code for both kind of data.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? In my original function, there are several variables I calculate in the `summarise` function and I don't want to maintain both parts separately.

Here is an example.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(s=rep(c('a','b'), each=10),
                  p=rep(letters[1:5], 4),
                  v=runif(20))
df2 <- data.frame(p=rep(letters[1:5], each=4),
                  v=runif(20))

avgP <- function(df) {
  if('s' %in% names(df)) {
    df %>% 
      group_by(s, p) %>% 
      summarise(avg=mean(v))
  } else {
    df %>% 
      group_by(p) %>% 
      summarise(avg=mean(v))
  }
}

avgP(df1)
avgP(df2)
```

My preferred solution would be something like `group_by` is just ignoring the missing column and will group only by `p` when I work on `df2`.

Comment: Are the variables the same in each data set? (apart from `s` of course)? Maybe use SE

Comment: What do you mean by SE? Yes they are basically the same.

Comment: [Have a look at this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). Also @akrun's answer uses SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `intersect`

```
avgP1 <- function(df){
  df %>% 
  group_by_(.dots =  intersect(names(df), c("s", "p"))) %>% 
  summarise(avg=mean(v))
 }

avgP1(df1)
avgP1(df2)
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very nice solution. Can I use this in a similar way if the grouping column is completely absent? To group or not to group... So to say :-)

Comment: @drmariod In the current setup, if there are no 's' or 'p' columns, it gives the average of the whole 'v' i.e. `df3 <- df2[-1]; avgP1(df3) #avg
      <dbl>
1 0.5880442;  mean(df3$v)
#[1] 0.5880442`

`

Comment: This is perfect. I wasn't aware of all these `_` functions, I just thought that they would help with naming conflicts... In my original function I use also `tidyr::gather` and now switching to `tidyr::gather_` gives me much more possibilities. Thanks again!